# Is it a good idea to message interviewers after drawn out recruitment process?

Tags: communication, job-offer, new-job, united-kingdom, telecommute

Basically I interviewed and was offered a position at a company a few weeks ago.

After some back and forth negotiations I have finally accepted the offer and received my contract.

I was thinking to message the two people who interviewed me a short message something like:

> Hi both,
>
> Now everything is sorted just wanted to thank you for the opportunity
> and let you know I am looking forward to joining.
>
> Please let me know if there is anything I can do prior to my start
> date to ensure a smooth transition.
>
> Thank you.

I am sure they are getting an update from their HR department so I'm sure they already know this but would it be advised for me to do this? Or would it just seem superfluous?

This role is fully remote and UK based if that makes a difference.

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable thing to do. I do exactly this when asking if there's any specific things I could brush up on between the acceptance and the start date.

Answer (score 6):

As a UK based hiring manager, I will say that this is not something which happens all the time. That being said, I have had new hires contact me and ask if there is anything they should be looking at before they start with us, and I do have a ready prepared list I can send over should I be asked for it. From my perspective you are showing enthusiasm for the role and diligence I would want from a new starter, especially someone who is 100% remote, so if I were the interviewer in this case it is something I would be pleased to receive. However rather than "Hi Both," in this case I would rather see "Dear Person X and Person Y," as the former is probably a little too informal.

Also, try looking at it from this perspective: When is saying thank you and being enthusiastic a bad thing? The worst case as far as I can see is they ignore the email.

Answer (score 3):

I would think it unusual. Not particularly wrong, just unnecessary, they're interviewers not new friends.

HR are the people you will be onboarding with initially and they will handle further contacts etc,.